# How to publish a C# executable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, exe

I finished my first relative simple C# project with Visual Studio 2015. Now it's time to publish it.

The best option would be a standalone exe. That'd be ideal!

But after I lost hope to achieve that I felt ok with an installer. VS even offers a possibility for that, but it simply does not work. I can run the setup.exe, but not the .application file. I tried alot of things but it just doesn't work.

After 1-2 weeks the only solution I could think of was to publish the Release or Debug directory as a zip and tell the users to unpack it somewhere and create a link to the .exe file. But not even that works! It seems like the file does not only depend on the files in the current folder, but also on the parent directories! The only solution now would be to zip the whole visual studio project!

I don't know why all the solutions do not work for me. My project isn't that complicated and I just want a possibility to publish it somehow :(

Comment: Does your project have any dependencies that must be installed?  Can the user just not run the EXE from the RELEASE folder?  What error do they get?

Comment: Dependencies on parent directories mean that you have hard-coded paths. You shouldn't have to do anything other than copy the binaries and configuration files. No installer can fix hard-coded paths or dependencies

Comment: please, define `doesn't works`, it executes but raises an exception?, it doesn't execute at all?

Comment: I can run the exe from the release folder. But when I move the release folder to somewhere else, I cannot anymore. "Doesn't work" means it just doesn't start. Nothin happens. I never even got an exception :/

Comment: You're getting exceptions, you're receiving errors, but the question is, did you code your application to handle them, and display or log them while testing it out in a different environment.  ;)

Comment: And you obviously have hardcoded file paths. Fix that.

Comment: Publishing the Release folder by itself is designed to work (in fact it is almost certainly happening somewhere even while I'm typing).  For testing this, have you tried making a new "hello world" Console Application and publishing it to establish a known "happy path"?  If you do this, you can work your way up in complexity until you can better understand what is happening with your target project.

Answer (score 6):

> But after I lost hope to achieve that I felt ok with an installer.

Why? Easy enough. Even with DLLs just zip them - I have plenty of low budget games that come as a zip file.

> VS even offers a possibility for that,

No, it does not. Only EXTREMELY outdated versions do that. The VS installer project was retired. The WIX toolset is the way to go these days - look it up at Google.

> After 1-2 weeks the only solution I could think of

I'd advise you to use a Windows Installer. Office and Visual Studio all come in installer form.

The way to go is the WIX toolkit.

> It seems like the file does not only depend on the files in the current 
>   folder, but also on the parent directories!

What is the question here? Hardcoding file paths into an executable results in programs that do not run when they are copied to other locations? Guess how to fix this? Do not hardcode paths. This is not an installer issue - this is simply a buggy program. NOTHING in a .NET exe has hardcoded paths unless it is made so.

And before you do even more bad things: never store editable data in the exe folder - this is what special folders are for. Once properly installed, the exe and the folder it resides in (Actually the whole install folder) are read only for normal users. Windows Standard for maybe 10 years or so...

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Squirrel.Windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) with good success. It handles the update story very well. Clickonce also works. Squirrel is used by Atom and Slack desktop apps and Clickonce is used by the Github Desktop App.

Comment: _Clickonce also works_ yet, Squirrel's catchline is **It's like ClickOnce but Works** :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/) to make the installer. You should add it to VisualStudio, make the configuration file and just deploy.

I've used WiX and it did installation packages OK.

Also there is another product: [dotnetinstaller](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/). I didn't use it.

A quick [tutorial is here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html):

*I suppose commercial products you will not use at this time.*

Comment: Wix has a bit of a learning curve...

Comment: Actually they do - the output is a standard MSI... hard to see what made it. I think WIX is the technology that actually does the Visual Studio installer (commercial) - I remember reading this in a blog post... Ah, wikipedia.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX - no commercial project? YOU JOKE... "After its release in 2004, Microsoft has used WiX to package Office 2007, SQL Server 2005, Visual Studio 2005/2008, and other products"

Comment: And WIX Has a low learning curve. It is quite straight MSI specifications in XML. MSI has a learning curve, but when you make an installer.... better have a clue how installers work on windows ;) WIX took me just 2-3 hours for my first product, coming from Installshield years ago.

Comment: agree, for first time it can take a while to manage it ;)